# Subset a numeric matrix with a numeric vector of column values

Tags: r, matrix, subset

This is a simple problem but I have not found an explicit solution in the archives.  Say I have a matrix m:

```
m <- structure(c(2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 
            1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
            0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
            0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 26, 18, 26, 18, 
            22, 21, 13, 22, 27, 20, 27, 24, 18, 21, 18, 22, 16, 22, 19, 15, 
            22, 27, 20, 20, 17), .Dim = c(25L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
                                                                     c("r", "s", "t", "u")))
```

And want to take a subset of the matrix containing the vector of some values in column u:

```
vec <- c(20, 21, 22, 24, 26)
```

In other words select the rows containing those values.  Suggestions on how to do that or a link to the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `which()` and `%in%` but you can use directly only `%in%` (Many thanks and the credit for **@GKi**):

```
#Code
newmat <- m[m[,'u'] %in% vec,]
```

Output:

```
      r s t  u
 [1,] 2 2 0 26
 [2,] 1 1 0 26
 [3,] 0 0 2 22
 [4,] 2 2 2 21
 [5,] 2 1 1 22
 [6,] 1 2 0 20
 [7,] 2 2 2 24
 [8,] 2 0 1 21
 [9,] 2 0 1 22
[10,] 1 0 1 22
[11,] 0 1 0 22
[12,] 2 0 0 20
[13,] 0 0 2 20
```

Comment: An Alternative without `which`: `m[m[,"u"] %in% vec,]`

Comment: @SteveM Always a pleasure helping you, dear :)